# using inline svg with imagemagick

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I'm trying to determine the best way to convert from an inline SVG image to a png image (the svg is dynamically generated and changes based on user input).
Right now I have:

```
 <?php
$svgtest = '
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <text x="5" y="12">hi</text>
</svg>
';

exec("convert \"$svgtest\" \"test.png\" ");
?>
```

But that isn't working.

Comment: What is the error message that you are receiving? And you probably also want to include your OS and version of ImageMagick in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ImageMagick extension and the following code:

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('white'));
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg width="100" height="100"><text x="5" y="12">hi</text></svg>';
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->writeImage("out.png");
```

Note that SVG string has xml declaration.

To use the command line, you could always read the STDIN or just put the string into file and then process it. However this is much more vulnerable for some malicious user input.

```
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><svg width='100' height='100'><text x='5' y='12'>hi</text></svg>" | convert - out2.png
```

To do it just pass the above line into `exec()`

Comment: I can't seem to install imagemagick. It just throws up an error of class not defined.
As for the second example, that's not working either.
`<?php
exec( echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><svg width='100' height='100'><text x='5' y='12'>hi</text></svg>" | convert - out2.png );
?>`

That just throws up:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\virtual\amiibo\pngTest.php on line 2`

Comment: echo in this case is a system program, so you shoul encapsulate this in qotes as well. try this:


`exec(" echo \"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><svg width='100' height='100'><text x='5' y='12'>hi</text></svg>\" | convert - out2.png );")`

Comment: I see that you are using xamp so getting all those quotes and lower- greater than signs with window's echo may be troublesome. Maybe something putting svg into the file first should do the job:

```$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><svg width="100" height="100"><text x="5" y="12">hi</text></svg>';
file_put_contents("temp.svg", $svg);
exec("convert temp.svg out3.png");```

Comment: While that does work, I was wanting to avoid saving anything to the server. (The example you gave saves a 'temp.svg' file to the server).

Comment: ok, it is doable win windows but requires bizzare angle brackets escaping. note that unix command will surely differ:

`exec("echo ^^^<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?^^^>^^^<svg width='100' height='100'^^^>^^^<text x='5' y='12'^^^>hi^^^</text^^^>^^^</svg^^^> | convert - out4.png");`

Comment: Awesome that seems to be doing the trick. Just out of curiousity though, what do the carets do to make it work? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: This is tricky as when pipe is used expression is parsed twice. Therefore you need 3 carets. More info here: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html in "Escaping the pipeline" section.